# Can I get the days for this vector time?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I got this code that let me produce a prediction of the next five days in hours

I wanna get the 5 days names of the vector output ,I'm getting some problems cause this works with GetHours and will change at the time so it's been a little difficult.

```
var d = new Date();
var time = [];
var horas = (d.getHours());
var num = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
  if (horas >= 24) {
    horas === 0;
  } else {
    horas = horas + 3;
    if (horas >= 24) {
      horas = 0;
    }
  }
  time.push((horas + ':00'));

}
console.log(time);
```

with this output:

```
(39) ["3:00" ,"6:00" ,"9:00" ,"12:00" ,"15:00" ,"18:00" ,"21:00" ,"0:00" ,"3:00" ,"6:00" ,"9:00" ,"12:00" ,"15:00" ,"18:00" ,"21:00" ,"0:00" ,"3:00" ,"6:00" ,"9:00" ,"12:00" ,"15:00" ,"18:00" ,"21:00" ,"0:00" ,"3:00" ,"6:00" ,"9:00" ,"12:00" ,"15:00" ,"18:00" ,"21:00" ,"0:00" ,"3:00" ,"6:00" ,"9:00" ,"12:00" ,"15:00" ,"18:00" ,"21:00"]
```

expected result
time vector and 
days vector

```
(5)["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"];
```

Comment: `["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][d.getDay()]`

Comment: `getDay()`? see:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp, also, [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) is a great package for working with dates, particularly the [format function](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format)

Comment: also, this seems wrong `horas === 0;`, that is an equals comparison operator. do you just want to assign the value 0 to horas with `horas = 0`?

Comment: it is also not clear to me what you are trying to achieve or why you have chosen the logic you have to achieve it.   perhaps you could clarify what you mean by ‘prediction of the next five days in hours’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the 5 days name from the `current day`, then you can do by maintaining a `weekDays` array like these:

```js
var d = new Date();
    var time = [];
    var expectedDays = [];
    var weekDays = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    var horas = (d.getHours());
    var num = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
     
      if (horas >= 24) {
        horas === 0;
        expectedDays.push(weekDays[(d.getDay()+(num++))%7]);
      } else {
        horas = horas + 3;
        if (horas >= 24) {
          horas = 0;
          expectedDays.push(weekDays[(d.getDay()+(num++))%7]);
        }
      }
      time.push((horas + ':00'));
    
    }
    console.log(time);
    console.log(expectedDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a `weekDays` array and count each time your day is changed by incrementing `num` and get the vector with `weekDays.slice(0, num)`:

```js
var d = new Date();
var time = [];
var horas = (d.getHours());
var num = 0;
var day = new Date().getDay();
var weekDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
for (i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
  if (horas >= 24) {
    horas = 0;
    num++;
  } else {
    horas = horas + 3;
    if (horas >= 24) {
      horas = 0;
      num++;
    }
  }
  time.push((horas + ':00'));

}
console.log(weekDays.slice(day, weekDays.length).concat(weekDays.slice(0, (num + day) % 7)));
//console.log(time);
```

Comment: For me today is Tuesday, but the result array starts on Monday.

Comment: @shrys if we take today is saturday means `new Date().getDay()=6` then it will return array of just one elements

Comment: @Hrv thanks again! I really need to think and first and then code :P